# Execute SolidWorks in background and exit with VBA macro

Tags: vba, background, macros, exit, solidworks

I am trying to do a complex geometry using SolidWorks and a VBA macro that I launch it with a batch script.

Firstly I did a simple macro to check if it is possible to run solidworks in background, creating a new part, doing a simple cube and then save it & close it.

Two things happens that I don't want to: the solidworks GUI actually is shown in my screen and the solidworks don't automatically exit after saving the document. It just closes the current part but not the software. The document is perfectly saved and the geometry is correct. It is a problem because my main batch macro cannot continue running unless I close the software manually.

Here is the code:

```
Dim swApp As Object

Dim Part As Object
Dim boolstatus As Boolean
Dim longstatus As Long, longwarnings As Long

Sub main()

Set swApp = _
Application.SldWorks

Set Part = swApp.NewDocument("C:\ProgramData\SolidWorks\SOLIDWORKS 2015\templates\Pieza.prtdot", 0, 0, 0)

' "Pieza" means part
swApp.ActivateDoc2 "Pieza1", False, longstatus

Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc

Dim myModelView As Object

' Use SolidWorks in background mode
swApp.Visible = False

Set myModelView = Part.ActiveView

myModelView.FrameState = swWindowState_e.swWindowMaximized

' Select lateral view and insert a sketch. Then extrude it
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("Vista lateral", "PLANE", 0, 0, 0, False, 0, Nothing, 0)
Part.SketchManager.InsertSketch True
Part.ClearSelection2 True
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SetUserPreferenceToggle(swUserPreferenceToggle_e.swSketchAddConstToRectEntity, swUserPreferenceOption_e.swDetailingNoOptionSpecified, False)
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SetUserPreferenceToggle(swUserPreferenceToggle_e.swSketchAddConstLineDiagonalType, swUserPreferenceOption_e.swDetailingNoOptionSpecified, True)

Dim vSkLines As Variant

vSkLines = Part.SketchManager.CreateCornerRectangle(0, 0, 0, -0.144655684475683, 8.79061467198382E-02, 0)
Part.ClearSelection2 True
Part.SketchManager.InsertSketch True
Part.ShowNamedView2 "*Trimétrica", 8
Part.ClearSelection2 True
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("Croquis1", "SKETCH", 0, 0, 0, False, 4, Nothing, 0)

Dim myFeature As Object

Set myFeature = Part.FeatureManager.FeatureExtrusion2(True, False, False, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.01, False, False, False, False, 1.74532925199433E-02, 1.74532925199433E-02, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, 0, 0, False)

Part.SelectionManager.EnableContourSelection = False
longstatus = Part.SaveAs3("C:\tmp_SW\part.SLDPRT", 0, 2)

' I tried to use a variable as a string, however using "swApp.QuitDoc Part.GetTitle" gives the same result
Dim myTitle As String

myTitle = Part.GetTitle

swApp.QuitDoc myTitle

End Sub
```

I hope the spanish words won't be a problem for understanding the text.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, few days of research and I have found this beautiful example:

[SolidWorks Example](http://help.solidworks.com/2012/English/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks_Visible_or_BackGround_Example_VB.htm)

And the key to my answer was:

```
Sub Macro3()

     Dim swApp As Object

     Dim Part As Object

     Set swApp = CreateObject("SldWorks.Application")

     ' Whether this value was true or false I got the same. GUI is shown on screen... 
     swApp.Visible = True


     ' First put swApp and then set it to nothing, to close the document.
     swApp.ExitApp

     Set swApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I hope this will help you all. Best regards.

Comment: can you please tell me how do you run this script? I have a macro code which I would like to run from the Windows command line preferrably without opening the Solidworks application